# Downloading a csv.gz file from url in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, url, gzip

I'm having trouble downloading a csv.gz file from a url I have no problem downloading a tar.gz file. For the csv.gz file I'm able to extract the .gz file and read my csv file it would just be handy if I could use an URL instead of having the csv-1.0.csv.gz before hand

This works:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.mywebsite.com/csv-1-0.tar.gz','csv-1-0.tar.gz')
```

This does not work:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.mywebsite.com/csv-1-0.csv.gz','csv-1-0.csv.gz')
```

I get this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xad' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: What does *This does not work* mean? An exception? No error message but no file?

Comment: I get this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xad' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace to your question? I'd like to know exactly which lines have the error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As suggested at the very beginning of the docs for [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html), the excellent [`requests`](http://requests.readthedocs.org/) module is recommended for higher-level http client interfaces. The code is quite straightforward:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/csv-1-0.csv.gz"
filename = url.split("/")[-1]
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    r = requests.get(url)
    f.write(r.content)
```

Basically, after assigning the URL and the destination file name, you open the destination file for writing in binary mode, request the file, then write the content of the request to the file. Done and done.

Comment: I have done what you have above and it does not work. When csv-1-0.csv.gz downloaded and i open it up in notepad it's simple HTML? Same happen when i try to download a zip folder. Thanks.

Comment: @EvanRyan what are the contents of the HTML file? This probably means that either the server is misconfigured somehow, or the link has moved (HTTP 404). Can you download the file from within your web browser? If so, then you need to properly set the headers for your GET request.

Comment: I did not properly set the headers for the GET request. It's working now. Thanks.