# How to download a file (csv.gz) from a url using Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.7

As with others who have posted in the past, I cannot figure out to download a csv.gz file from a URL in Python 3.7. I see posts but they only post a 2kb file.

I am a 100% newbie using Python.  What follows is the code for one file that I am trying to obtain. I can't even do that. The final goal would be to request all files that start with 2019* using python.  Please try the code below to save the file. As others stated, the file is just a name without the true content - Ref: [Downloading a csv.gz file from url in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561746/downloading-a-csv-gz-file-from-url-in-python)

```
import requests
url = 'https://public.bitmex.com/?prefix=data/trade/20191026.csv.gz'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('20191026.csv.gz', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Yields:
Out[40]:
1245 
I've tried "wget" and urllib.request along with "urlretrieve" also.

I wish I could add a screenshot or attach a file. The file created is 2kb and not even a csv.gz file. But the true file that I can download from a web browser is 78mb. The file is 20191026.csv.gz not that it matters as they all do the same thing. The location is https://public.bitmex.com/?prefix=data/trade/
Again, if you know of a way to obtain all the files using a filter such that 2019*csv.gz would be fantastic.

Comment: Are you getting any exception when you run the code?

Comment: When I run the above code, I get - Out[4]:1234. No error. Just a file that is clearly not the file I download. Instead of the file being a compressed csv, it's a 2kb file. When I send this to note pad it reads..... (Truncated as it does not fit)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>BitMEX Public Data</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; connect-src https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com; script-src 'sha384-

Comment: By the way, the above works as an example to download an icon file.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to download the files from `https://public.bitmex.com/?prefix=data/trade/`.
To achieve your final goal of download all the files starting from 2019* you have to do in 3 steps

1) you read the content of `https://public.bitmex.com/?prefix=data/trade/`

2) convert the content into an list, from that filter out the file names which starting from 2019.

3) from the result list try to download the csv using the example which you referring.

Hope this approach will help you
Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, Parthasarathy. My problem is that the file is not the file I download. I can download other file types no problem. It almost like it does not understand gz files. Try it. In the browser, it's a multi-megabyte file. In Python, it downloads a 2kb header. Maybe there some other setting to download a compressed file? I'd really like to figure it out.My work around is a script in Windows. Sad.